# Using Javascript to reference a VF field and update database

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to reference a VF form field in my javascript and update in the database. I've got the update part working, but I'm still having a lot of problem trying to referencing "temp_approver" in my code: `var ta= $j('input[id$="temp_approver"]').val();`

Not sure if this is a syntax error or maybe I didn't set up  correctly in the beginning. Thank you!

```
 < apex:pageBlockSection >    
    < apex:inputField value="{!User.Temp_Approver__c}" required="true" id="temp_approver"/>
 < /apex:pageBlockSection>


  < script src="../../soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js">< /script>

  < apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.gonzoCore, 'forcetk.js')}" />   
  < script>
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            function saveAlert()
            {

                var manager = new sforce.SObject("User");
                var arrUpdateManager = new Array();
                var userid = "{!$User.Id}";
                var ta= $j('input[id$="temp_approver"]').val();
                manager.set("Id", userid);
                manager.Temp_Approver__c = ta;
                arrUpdateManager.push(manager);
                    var result = sforce.connection.update(arrUpdateManager);     
                        if(result[0].getBoolean("success"))
                        {
                            alert("Great Success!");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(result[0].errors.message);
                        }               
            }
  < /script>
```

Comment: are you calling saveAlert() ?? Do you have any error on javascript console? try console.log($j('input[id$="temp_approver"]')) to check your selector. In addition I think "set" function is not need.  manager.set("Id", userid); Use direct assignation insted of "set"

Comment: Yes, I'm calling saveAlert() via a button. if i hardcode manager.Temp_Approver__c it works like a charm. But I'm having issue pointing to the Temp_Approver__c field in my VF page.

Comment: Using the browser console, what is the result of executing just this jQuery selector? `$j('input[id$="temp_approver"]');` Does it return any items in the collection? Does it return more than one item in the collection?

Comment: This execution is triggered off a button, when i click it, i get an error of - "Temp Approver: id value of incorrect type: [object Object]"

Comment: Which is temp_approver type?

Comment: Could you post the code for the button as well? Also, did you try @MarkPond suggestion?

Comment: Is `Temp_Approver__c` a lookup field? What type of an object does it lookup to? Does the type of that object match the value which you've got in the JavaScript `var ta`? The idea here being similar to putting a `Contact.Id` into a field which is defined as a lookup to `User`.

Comment: Assuming Temp_aprrover__c is a look field. I suggest you should you $j("[id*='temp_approver']").val(), this will return the id of the record that is selected. But if you use the $ as a selector you will get the name of the record that you have selected.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get a value from a visualforce component with jQuery is `j$('input[id$="salesforce_id"]').val()` which you're already doing.

Sounds like you have an issue elsewhere.  I'd suggest stepping through your code in the browser javascript console line by line to figure out what's not working.

Comment: To be precise, the most correct way is `jQuery('[id="{!$Component.your_vf_element_id}"]')`

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit my comment. The ends with syntax is handy but could cause unintended side-effects if there are elements in a repeating structure as they will all end with the same ID string. (for instance, a repeater containing an input text field with an ID of `firstname`: every `firstname` input field in the repeated structure will end with `firstname` and the generated id of these individual elements will contain which array index contained them.)

Answer (score 1):

If your code is resulting in the error "Temp Approver: id value of incorrect type: [object Object]", then that must be an error thrown by the "sforce.connection.update" call. It sounds like Temp_Approver__c is a Reference type field (i.e. a Lookup or Master-Detail), which makes things tricky because Visualforce generates *multiple* input elements for each apex:inputField bound to a Reference. One of the generated input elements will be [type=text] (this is the one that you see and are currently selecting; it displays the label), and then there will be a few input[type=hidden] -- each with a special suffix on its generated DOM ID (e.g. _lkid, _mod). The ID value is in the hidden field with the suffix "_lkid". You need to set this ID value into your SObject, not the label. The selector you want for that is:

```
var approverId = $j('input[type=hidden][id$="temp_approver_lkid"]').val();
```

HOWEVER, this is not a complete solution; this will only work when the field was bound to a valid ID as the page was generated. If there was no initial value, then the _lkid value will be all "0"'s. Worse yet, once the user manually types a new value into the [type=text] (as opposed to using the Search icon), then the _lkid will be made blank -- because it doesn't know the ID for a typed-in label until you query the database. You would need to manually query the database to find the label's matching ID value against that relationship, and it may find 0, 1, or >1 matches. Essentially, you would be rebuilding the logic behind Salesforce's Lookup widget. For these reasons, you should try to stick with the  field for save logic, if at all possible.

However, here is the test you would use to detect when you need to query for the ID value:

```
// test for an ID value that is blank or all 0's:
if (/^(?:0+|\s*)$/.test(approverId)) {
    /* TODO: query the database */
}
```